# Exclude files from causing GAE server restart

Tags: python, google-app-engine, go

Is there a way to avoid GAE server restart when the file within the root of my application changes. I use Go (GAE server is python based) runtime.

The intention is not to reload the server when some of my files (html, css, js files; which are under /static folder) changes. This is to avoid startup time during development. Any way to exclude them from file watch.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the files that comprise your application, the application will need to restart in order to serve the new files.

If this is a real sticking point for you, I would suggest hosting the files elsewhere, like a CDN. Your application and the static resources that it employs do not need to be all in the same place.

Comment: I created a kind of CMS in appengine python, where all the "static" resources (html, text, images, javascript, css, pdf) are served from the blobstore. In this way you can change the content on the fly.

Comment: @Adam thanks for the suggestion. that makes sense, but during development, I probably needs to keep the file locally. Say my server is handling REST requests, and should decouple the client side development. I don't know much about GAE options, but is it possible to move the static files out of my server project, but still served by the server?

Comment: The comment from @voscausa is a good one. You could also have your static files served by AppEngine but as part of a separate project. I don't know of a way to do what you want directly.